# How to generate prime numbers by iter method?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have the following code, no error is showing, but still no output.
I need help to correct this code.

```
class primenumber:
    def __iter__(self,end):
        self._end=end

    def checkprimenumber(self,n):
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n%i==0:
                return false
        return true

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 2
        if self._end>2:
            for n in range(2,self._end):
                if checkprimenumber(n):
                    yield n
def main():
    r=primenumber(150)
    for n in r:
        print (n)

if __name__ == "__main__":main
```

Comment: fix the indentation.

Comment: thats  not the problem. i made some change while pasting.....here

Comment: then fix those changes by [edit]ing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some small problems:

```
class Primenumber(object):
    def __init__(self, end): # Init instead of __iter__ here
        self._end = end

    def checkprimenumber(self,n):
        for i in range(2,n):
            if n%i==0:
                return False
        return True

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 2
        if self._end>2:
            for n in range(2,self._end):
                if self.checkprimenumber(n): # Need to call to self.
                    yield n
def main():
    r=Primenumber(150)
    for n in r:
        print(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expect for those 2 small problems I found no further error. But normally the error messages tell you what is missing and you should be able to fix it by yourself. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This code is unlikely to do anything since it calls no method.

Add parentheses to the main call and remove the indentation before the `if` -

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Afterwards, you'll see a few errors in the code (such as missing constructor and calls to member methods without `self.`)

Comment: Or simply: "Add parentheses" ^^

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vishnu\Desktop\python practice\sample.py", line 22, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "C:\Users\vishnu\Desktop\python practice\sample.py", line 17, in main
    r=primenumber(20)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
[Finished in 0.121s]

Comment: Great, so now you get feedback on the errors in the code.

Comment: @Visprasad a small hint would be why is there two `__iter__` method

Comment: sorry first one is constructor